# MemoryError while reading and writing a 40GB CSV... where is my leak?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory

I have a 40GB CSV file which I have to output with different column subsets as CSVs once again, with a check that there are no `NaN`s in the data. I opted to use Pandas, and a minimal example of my implementation looks like this (inside a function `output_different_formats`):

```
# column_names is a huge list containing the column union of all the output
#  column subsets
scen_iter = pd.read_csv('mybigcsv.csv', header=0, index_col=False,
                        iterator=True, na_filter=False,
                        usecols=column_names)
CHUNKSIZE = 630100
scen_cnt = 0
output_names = ['formatA', 'formatB', 'formatC', 'formatD', 'formatE']
# column_mappings is a dictionary mapping the output names to their
#  respective column subsets. 
while scen_cnt < 10000:
    scenario = scen_iter.get_chunk(CHUNKSIZE)
    if scenario.isnull().values.any():
        # some error handling (has yet to ever occur)
    for item in output_names:
        scenario.to_csv(item, float_format='%.8f',
                        columns=column_mappings[item],
                        mode='a', header=True, index=False, compression='gzip')

    scen_cnt+=100
```

I thought this was safe memory-wise, as I am iterating over the file in chunks with `.get_chunk()` and never placing the whole CSV in a DataFrame at once, just appending the next chunk to the end of each respective file.

However about 3.5 GBs into the output generation, my program crashed with the following MemoryError in the `.to_csv` line with a long Traceback ending with the following

```
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 838, in take_nd
    out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

Why am I getting a MemoryError here? Do I have a memory leak somewhere in my program or am I misunderstanding something? Or could the program be incited to just randomly fail on writing to CSV for that particular chunk and maybe I should consider reducing the chunksize?

*Full Traceback*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/AppData/A/MRM/Eric/output_formats.py", line 128, in <module>
    output_different_formats(real_world=False)
  File "D:/AppData/A/MRM/Eric/output_formats.py", line 50, in clocked
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/AppData/A/MRM/Eric/output_formats.py", line 116, in output_different_formats
    mode='a', header=True, index=False, compression='gzip')
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1188, in to_csv
    decimal=decimal)
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 1293, in __init__
    self.obj = self.obj.loc[:, cols]
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1187, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 720, in _getitem_tuple
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1323, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 966, in _getitem_iterable
    result = self.obj.reindex_axis(keyarr, axis=axis, level=level)
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2519, in reindex_axis
    fill_value=fill_value)
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1852, in reindex_axis
    {axis: [new_index, indexer]}, fill_value=fill_value, copy=copy)
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1876, in _reindex_with_indexers
    copy=copy)
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3157, in reindex_indexer
    indexer, fill_tuple=(fill_value,))
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3238, in _slice_take_blocks_ax0
    new_mgr_locs=mgr_locs, fill_tuple=None))
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 853, in take_nd
    allow_fill=False)
  File "D:\AppData\A\MRM\Eric\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 838, in take_nd
    out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to call the garbage collector in the loop (`gc.collect()`). As a workaround you could also try a 64-bit version of python.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Trying with `gc.collect()` now, won't know if it was succesful for another few hours. Why might 64-bit Python help?

Comment: 64-bit python allows more memory allocation (of course you need the physical memory / swap on your system and a 64-bit windows). This won't fix the memory leak but will delay it, hopefully until termination of your program.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I see. I'll let you know if `gc.collect()` solves it in a bit, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for now has been to manually call the garbage collector with `gc.collect()`

```
while scen_cnt < 10000:
    scenario = scen_iter.get_chunk(CHUNKSIZE)
    if scenario.isnull().values.any():
        # some error handling (has yet to ever occur)
    for item in output_names:
        scenario.to_csv(item, float_format='%.8f',
                        columns=column_mappings[item],
                        mode='a', header=True, index=False, compression='gzip')
        gc.collect()
    gc.collect()
```

The memory consumption remains steady after adding these lines, however it is still unclear to my *why* there is a memory issue with this approach.

Comment: It does not seem to be about a memory leak, because calling the garbage collector would not help you in such a case. It is just likely how the allocation of memory is implicitely done within the diverse libraries you are using. I would be suprised that as a library user you could do anything about it.

Comment: I would love to learn what a library user is supposed to do in your case. :) But I can't imagine you created any memory leak here, nor did your libraries.